# Generalised type constraints and this

Tags: scala

I'm trying to add a method to a generic class that should only work for some types, and I understand that a [generalised type constraint](https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/scala-generics-generalized-type-constraints/) is a way to achieve this. But I'm struggling to use this when the instance itself (`this`) needs to be passed, like so:

```scala
case class Sum(x: Value[Int], y: Value[Int]) {
  def apply(): Int = x.v + y.v
}

case class Value[T](v: T) {
  def plus(y: Value[Int])(using ev: T =:= Int): Int = Sum(this, y)()
}
```

I would have thought that the `T =:= Int` would have given the compiler enough information to know that `this` is a `Value[Int]`, but it complains:

```txt
-- [E007] Type Mismatch Error: -------------------------------------------------
6 |  def plus(y: Value[Int])(using ev: T =:= Int): Int = Sum(this, y)()
  |                                                          ^^^^
  |                                         Found:    (Value.this : Value[T])
  |                                         Required: Value[Int]
```

Is there a way to do what I am wanting here and have the compiler know that `this` is, indeed, `Value[Int]`?

Thanks for any help! ✌️

Comment: In this case you can help compiler with `asInstanceOf` - `def plus(y: Value[Int])(using ev: T =:= Int): Int = Sum(this.asInstanceOf[Value[Int]], y)()`

Comment: Thanks, but is there no way of doing this without essentially circumventing the type checker?

Comment: You can also do `def plus(y: Value[Int])(using ev: T =:= Int): Int = Sum(Value(v), y)()` =)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately in practice, I need this to work within a trait, where there won't be a `v` with type `T`. My example is simplified above to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, passing `T =:= Int`, is not enough.

The way `=:=` works is that if at some place the compiler sees that implicit/given of `T =:= T` is required, it provides it.

At the call site of `value1.plus(value2)` the compiler can see that and create this evidence.

Once it is obtained, here - inside `plus`, `=:=` is NOT becoming a magic hint for the compiler for every type. It becomes an implicit conversion. If you'd do:

```
case class Value[T](v: T) {
  def plus(y: Value[Int])(using ev: Value[T] =:= Value[Int]): Int = Sum(this, y)()
}
```

You'd see that it works, but with the help of e.g. IntelliJ + "show implicits" hint option you'd see that compiler turns your code into:

```
case class Value[T](v: T) {
  def plus(y: Value[Int])(using ev: Value[T] =:= Value[Int]): Int = Sum(ev(this), y)()
}
```

This implicit conversion would work out of the box only on matching types.

However, there are other options:

```
case class Value[T](v: T) {
  def plus(y: Value[Int])(using ev: T =:= Int): Int = Sum(ev.subsctituteCo[Value](this), y)()
}
```

`ev.subsctituteCo` lets you add a wrapper type and cast the wrapped value from the type on the left to the type on the right.

You could also cast it yourself with `.asInstanceOf` (less elegant) or unwrap and rewrap the value like suggested in the comments.